# Distance between same point in two different images not consistent - OpenCV/C++

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, homography, opencv-stitching

So I have two Thermal images (Potato quality I know but it is what I have to work with), the first two images in this album. I am using some code from a tutorial that is super common but have edited a lot of it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU26e.jpg

So what I am doing in my code is

```
1. Detecting KeyPoints
2. Describe the KeyPoints
3. Match the KeyPoints
4. Keep only good points
5. Gather both Query and Train points
6. Find Homography
7. Warp one of the images
8. Repeat the above steps for the warped image and the other original image
```

Now my question is: Should the change in the (x,y) distance between two of the same points on the two different images be the same for every set of points?

The whole frame is moving in the same direction so no matter what matching points we look at the change should be the same should it not?

What I am finding is that the points all different in the distance, some are 5 pixels different and some are 700 pixels, the only thing I can think is happening is that the match is not actually good and it is comparing two points that are no where near the same point in the separate frames.

I need to know what the offset is so that I can overlay one frame on top of the other then average out the pixel values that are overlapping and build a new images from the composite/average of the two originals.

My code I am using is below:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "stitch.cpp"
#include "opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void readme();
Mat describe(Mat img, vector<KeyPoint> key);
vector<KeyPoint> detect(Mat img);
vector<DMatch> match(Mat descriptionOne, Mat descriptionTwo);

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap("vid.mp4");

    vector<Mat> Vimg;

    cout << "Grabbing Images" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Grabbing Frame" << i << endl;
        Mat temp;
        cap.read(temp);
        Vimg.push_back(temp);
        imwrite("image" + to_string(i) + ".jpg", temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
            cap.grab();
    }
    //Mat cimg1 = Vimg[0];
    //Mat cimg2 = Vimg[1];

    Mat cimg1 = imread("cap1.png");
    Mat cimg2 = imread("cap2.png");

    cout << "Starting Stitching" << endl;

    //Converting the original images to grayscale
    Mat img1, img2;
    cvtColor(cimg1, img1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(cimg2, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //Detecting Keypoints for original two images
    vector<KeyPoint> keypointOne = detect(img1), keypointTwo = detect(img2);

    Mat mkeypointOne, mkeypointTwo;

    drawKeypoints(cimg1, keypointOne, mkeypointOne, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    drawKeypoints(cimg2, keypointTwo, mkeypointTwo, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    imwrite("keypointOne.jpg", mkeypointOne);
    imwrite("keypointTwo.jpg", mkeypointTwo);

    //Computing descriptors 
    Mat descriptionOne = describe(img1, keypointOne), descriptionTwo = describe(img2, keypointTwo);

    //Matching descriptors  
    vector<DMatch> matches = match(descriptionOne, descriptionTwo); 


    double max = 0;
    double min = 100;

    //Calculation of max and min distances
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min) min = dist;
        if (dist > max) max = dist;
    }

    vector<DMatch> goodMatches;

    //Keep only good matches
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 2*min)
            goodMatches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }

    //Localize
    vector<Point2f> obj;
    vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < goodMatches.size(); i++)
    {
        obj.push_back(keypointOne[goodMatches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypointTwo[goodMatches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    /*
    for (int k = 0; k < obj.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << "Point data for Match #" << k << endl;
        cout << "\tImage 1 Point: " << obj[k] << endl;
        cout << "\tImage 2 Point: " << scene[k] << endl;
    }*/

    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    //Warping the image to fit on first image
    Mat cwarpImage, warpImage;

    //TODO: figure out the right size for this image that is created
    warpPerspective(cimg2, cwarpImage, H, Size(img2.cols + img1.cols, img2.rows + img1.rows));

    /*
    Mat result;
    Mat half(warpImage, Rect(0, 0, img2.cols, img2.rows));
    cimg2.copyTo(half);
    */

    imwrite("warp.jpg", warpImage);

    //Processing Image
    cvtColor(cwarpImage, warpImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypointWarp = detect(warpImage);
    Mat descriptionWarp = describe(warpImage, keypointWarp);
    vector<DMatch> warpMatches = match(descriptionOne, descriptionWarp);
    Mat mkeypointWarp;
    drawKeypoints(cwarpImage, keypointWarp, mkeypointWarp, Scalar(0, 0, 255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    imwrite("keypointWarp.jpg", mkeypointWarp);

    Mat match;
    drawMatches(cimg1, keypointOne, warpImage, keypointWarp, warpMatches, match, Scalar(0, 0, 255), Scalar(255, 0, 0), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    //imshow("match", match);
    imwrite("matches.jpg", match);

    //Localize
    vector<Point2f> obj2;
    vector<Point2f> scene2;

    for (int i = 0; i < warpMatches.size(); i++)
    {
        obj2.push_back(keypointOne[warpMatches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene2.push_back(keypointWarp[warpMatches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }


    for (int k = 0; k < obj.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << "Point data for Match #" << k << endl;
        cout << "\tImage 1 Point: " << obj2[k] << endl;
        cout << "\tImage 2 Point: " << scene2[k] << endl;
    }

    vector<unsigned char> inliersMask;
    Mat H2 = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC, 3, inliersMask);

    vector<DMatch> inliers;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inliersMask.size(); i++)
    {
        if (inliersMask[i])
            inliers.push_back(warpMatches[i]);
    }

    warpMatches.swap(inliers);

    Mat match2;
    drawMatches(cimg1, keypointOne, warpImage, keypointWarp, warpMatches, match2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), Scalar(255, 0, 0), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    imwrite("homorgraphyOutlierMatch.jpg", match2);

    cout << "Writing Warp Image" << endl;
    imwrite("warpimage.jpg", warpImage);
    cout << H << endl;

    waitKey(0);
}

Mat describe(Mat img, vector<KeyPoint> key)
{
    Mat temp;
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    extractor.compute(img, key, temp);
    return temp;
}

vector<KeyPoint> detect(Mat img)
{
    vector<KeyPoint> temp;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
    detector.detect(img, temp);
    return temp;
}

vector<DMatch> match(Mat descriptionOne, Mat descriptionTwo)
{
    vector<DMatch> temp;
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
    matcher.match(descriptionOne, descriptionTwo, temp);    

    return temp;
}
```

EDIT:

I set Cross Check to true in the BFMatcher and implemented Homography outlier detection from Mastering_OpenCV. Here are the two new results. I was not sure if I was supposed to implement both cross check and KnnMatch so I only did cross check.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/79XSI.jpg

As you can see they are a lot better but there are still some there that should not be there. I ran it with both full color and thermal images. 
New code is above as well.

Comment: Well please define better the "moving in the same direction". If it is really a translation, assuming the camera has no distortion on the image then every point will have moved exactly the same (since that is the definition of a translation).

Comment: Yes sorry that is what I mean. The translation between the two frames should be the same for every point should it not. (There is no distortion)

Comment: Well in this case you can assume that every point moved the same so it makes matching much easier. You just need to find enough points and get the translation parameters from that.

Comment: OK, Dave's awnser below pointed out my matches are probably not correct as there are a lot of crossed lines. So I am going to enable cross check and apply the ratio test to try and remove outliers.

Comment: If you get enough good points you should be able to remove the outliers just fine

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will update when I apply cross check and ratio test.

Comment: distance in the images depends on many optical effects: perspective, parallaxe, LENS DISTORTION, etc. but as you can see in your two images, there are many bad matches left. you should filter the bad ones out after a robust homography computation

Answer (score 0):

While the change in distance between point correspondences won't be the same for all points in the general case, you wouldn't expect to have deltas of the order of 700 pixels with an image size of 1300ish.

by inspection of the images you've posted, it's clear that you have point correspondences which are not correct (simply, you have lots of crossed lines in your matches between images)

This suggests that your step 4 isn't doing a great job. You might want to try setting the second parameter of your Brute Force matcher to true to enable cross-check test:

```
 BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
```

You might also want to consider the ratio test for outlier removal as described here [How to apply Ratio Test in order to remove outliers in a multiple object detection matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710060/how-to-apply-ratio-test-in-order-to-remove-outliers-in-a-multiple-object-detecti)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was thinking. Will try both enabling true and looking at the ratio test. The steps I posted make sense though right?

Comment: In theory what you're proposing makes sense but it depends on what you want to do with the output combined image as to whether it's valid or not. If the variation in the distance of the images points from the camera is much smaller than the distance from the camera itself then a Homography is probably appropriate. If this doesn't hold then you may get a lot of parallax effects that will mean some points won't overlap post move and you could end up with duplication.

Comment: What will end up happening is I'll expand the overlaying over hundreds of frames to create a map the UAV covered. From there I have already written and tested to code to find hotspot contours based on a given value. So as long as the variation isn't outrageous I'm only looking for blobs of how anyway.

Comment: So I am looking at the Ratio Test and BFMatcher with cross check set, do I use both of them? Or should I just be using one?

Comment: That looks a lot better. You still have a few outliers but they're significantly reduced. You could try iterating - i.e. repeating the whole process again or you could consider using RANSAC to eliminate the outliers.  You might also want to try using the median displacement rather than the mean of all displacements as this may also help with accuracy.

Comment: I believe I am using the RANSAC already when computing Homography am I not? Also I will try the median but I was able to reduce them even further by apply an algorithm removes outliers whos mean difference between points lies outside of one Standard Deviation of the computed mean + std dev.